# How can I fix my Mac when When Connects to External Monitor (TV) gets blurred Text

Tags: macos, display, hdmi, resolution, television

I want to use a SANSUI TV as a display for my Mac. I have connected the TV with HDMI but the problem is it gets blurred text, it's not smooth at all. I have many resolutions with ALT on scaled but no smoothness. It was the same on windows also.
However, when connect with VGA it was clear and smooth as a normal monitor.

The resolution it shows:

> 1080p  1080i  720  480  1366x769  1240x...  ...  840x...

Do I need drivers or cabling or settings to change the blur?

Comment: What specific model of TV do you have? Do you know what resolutions it has is it a 720p monitor or a 1080p monitor?

Comment: It shows all if press with alt I have edited my question

Comment: If you don’t want to accept the answer, perhaps an edit to show a photo of the blur would help someone help you. Especially a windows / vs / Mac image

Answer (score 1):

> Under the ‘Display’ tab, hold down the OPTION / ALT key while you press on the ‘Scaled’ button alongside Resolution to reveal all available screen resolution options for the display

Try using this to see the actual resolution in numbers. Once you know what actual resolution is being used in HDMI you can better assess why the image isn't sharp.

Source: [Change your Mac display’s resolution](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/mac-help/mchl86d72b76/mac)
Source: [How to Show All Possible Screen Resolutions for a Display in Mac OS X](https://osxdaily.com/2015/08/27/show-all-display-resolutions-external-screen-mac/)